# Yii - Validate based on theme and views rather than model

Tags: php, yii

our system currently has themes that can be generated by the system and follows the same folder / file structure.

These themes all look at the same model, unfortunately it's getting to the point where different themes are requiring different required fields that won't ever be used in the other themes.

I've looked at scenarios but I don't think they are the right solution, is there not as easy as a solution as setting the fields to required in the view?

```
public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(

            array('username,forename,surname, type_id', 'required'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('prefix, forename, surname, email, telephone, address_id, type_id, company, company_role, bio, dob, create_time, update_time, plusGuest', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }
```

For example we have the username marked as required...but in another theme we aren't using a username in the form, now we can hide it and give it a default value on the form but I don't feel like this is the best solution. Maybe it is and I'm overthinking things!

basically, is there anyway to assign different rules based on different themes (keep in mind we are likely to have hundreds of these and they need to be dynamically generated or at least quickly changed on our end). The other solutions I've seen all seem to be based around knowing all the parameters and how many rules you need beforehand.

Comment: According to your need, this is the best way to use scenario for different rules condition. Then you can use these rules for different themes.

Comment: I think my issue was declaring the themes.  Definitely struggling to get my head around how this will work for a fully dynamic system

Comment: Create a mapping of themes and scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking out loud and this is not tested in this context by me, but could you put an if in the rules function and set one property in the model that is going to be a flag with which you will determine what layout is being used. Different layout value different set of rules. I've used this approach in search function of a model and it was working for me at the time. And it was only two options so it wasn't big or complex. This is not ideal, as a matter of fact it's hacky and not a Yii solution, but if you are desperate and adventurous try it.

Comment: Definitely need an outside solution like this I think, would require a lot of development time. The pitfalls of inheriting a half finished project from someone else!